# Bash: Process monitoring and manipulation

Tags: linux, bash

I have a C program that processes some input file. I'm using a Bash script to feed the input files one-by-one to this program, along with some other parameters. Each input file is processed by the program 4 times , each time by varying some parameters. You can think of it as an experiment to test the C program with different parameters.

This C program can consume memory very quickly (and can even take up more than 95% of the OS memory , resulting in slowing down the system). So, in my script, I'm monitoring 2 things for *every test run* of the program - The total running time, and the memory percentage consumed (obtained from `top` command) . When either of them ***first*** crosses a threshold, I kill the C program using `killall -q 0 processname` , and begin the next test run.

This is how my script is structured:

```
 # run in background
./program file_input1 file_input2 param1 param2 &

 # now monitor the process
 # monitor time     
 sleep 1
 ((seconds++))
 if [ $seconds -ge $timeout ]; then
     timedout=1
     break
 fi

 # monitor memory percentage used
 memused=`top -bn1 | grep \`pidof genpbddh2\` | awk '{print $10}' | cut -d'.' -f1`

 if [ $memused -ge $memorylimit ]; then
    overmemory=1
    break
 fi
```

This entire thing is run inside a loop which keeps generating new values for the paramaters to the C program.
When a program breaks out of the loop due to timeout or over memory limit usage, this command is executed:
`killall -q 0 program`

**The problem:**
My intention was , once the program is started in the background (1st line above), I can monitor it. Then go to the next run of the program. A sequential execution of test cases.
But, it seems all the *future runs* of the program have been schedule by the OS (Linux) for some reason. That is, if Test Run 1 is running, Test Runs 2,3,4..and so on are also scheduled somehow (without Run 1 having finished). At least, it seems that way from the below observation:
When I pressed Ctrl-C to end the script, it exited cleanly. But, new instances of the "program" are keeping on being created continuously. The script has ended, but the instances of the program are still being continuously started. I checked and made sure that the script has ended. Now , I wrote a script to infinitely check for instances of this program being created and kill it. And eventually, all the pre-scheduled instances of the program were killed and no more new ones were created. But it was all a lot of pain.

1. Is this the correct way to externally monitor a program?
2. Any clues on why this problem is occuring, and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you provide a complete, standalone reproducer for this issue?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement may be of interest to folks who find themselves at this question, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that a more correct way to monitor a program like this would be:

ulimit -v $memorylimit

With such a limit set any process will get killed if it uses too much virtual memory. It is also possible to set other limits like maximum cpu time used or maximum number of open files.

To see your current limits you can use

ulimit -a

Ulimit is for bash users, if you use tcsh the command to use is instead limit.